# Select as different user works in query but not in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, schema, sql-server-2016

Environment: SQL SERVER 2016
I am using the execute as user function in SQL to create a table specific to a session without using dynamic SQL.  When I run the code as a single query it performs exactly as expected. Working code is:

```
    DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @strSession AS NVARCHAR(256) 
    SET @strSession = 'SESSION_ABCD'

    SET @strSQL = 'CREATE SCHEMA ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @strSession + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(36)) + ''' '
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'CREATE USER ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'ALTER USER ' + @strSession + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::' + @strSession + ' TO ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)      

    SET @strSQL = 'GRANT CREATE TABLE TO ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE TO ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    EXECUTE AS USER = 'SESSION_ABCD'

    -- Create table without including default schema - OK
    -- Creates table SESSION_ABCD.Test as expected
    CREATE TABLE Test (MyValue INT)

    -- Select from table including schema name - OK         
    SELECT  *
    FROM    SESSION_ABCD.Test

    -- Select from table excluding schema name - Works outside of stored procedure
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Test

    REVERT
```

However if I run the same code inside a stored [procedure I get unexpected results.  Code for this is:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SetupUser
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strSession AS NVARCHAR(256) 
    SET @strSession = 'SESSION_ABCD'

    DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @strSQL = 'CREATE SCHEMA ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @strSession + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(36)) + ''' '
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'CREATE USER ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'ALTER USER ' + @strSession + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::' + @strSession + ' TO ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)      

    SET @strSQL = 'GRANT CREATE TABLE TO ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)

    SET @strSQL = 'GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE TO ' + @strSession
    PRINT (@strSQL) 
    EXEC (@strSQL)
END

GO

CREATE PROC dbo.SetupTable
AS
BEGIN

    EXECUTE AS USER = 'SESSION_ABCD'

    -- Create table without including default schema - OK
    -- Creates table SESSION_ABCD.Test as expected
    CREATE TABLE Test (MyValue INT)

    -- Select from table including schema name - OK         
    SELECT  *
    FROM    SESSION_ABCD.Test

    -- Select from table excluding schema name - Fails
    -- Expecting same result as above

    PRINT SCHEMA_NAME()
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Test

    REVERT
END

GO

EXEC dbo.SetupUser

EXEC dbo.SetupTable
```

When I execute the script above, the users/sessions/etc configure correctly. (Please note you need to remove these from the system to run them a second time.) In the SetupTable procedure the create table command executes against the default schema, however the select command needs to be qualified with the schema name.  While I could build the query up with Dynamic SQL to insert the schema name, this project is entirely around removing old dynamic sql code.

I will be honest and say this is not an approach I have used before, but seems to be the solution most suggested to solve another problem.  I'm hoping there is something basic that I am missing, but at the moment I am completely stumped.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second procedure is created in `dbo` schema, if you don't use fully qualified names within it, the default schema is **stored procedure schema** (`dbo` in your case), not user's default schema.

For example, you have user `A` with default schema `a`, schema `B,` and schema `dbo`.

You create a proc B.sp_test:

```
create proc B.sp_test as select * from test_tbl
```

Now user `A` executes this sp.

Table `test_tbl` is not schema qualified, so server first looks for `B.test_tbl`.
If the table exists, it selects from it. If no, it looks for `dbo.test_tbl`.
If the table is not found, you've got an error.

It's not user's default schema that is verified, but it's procedure's schema and then `dbo` schema that are verified.

That is different from table creation.
When user creates a table without qualifying it with the schema, it's default scema is used. And this is independent on WHERE the table is created, within sp or not.

How you can prove it to yourself?

Just create a procedure in a different schema.
Create 3 tables with the same name test_tbl, put them in your default schema, in dbo, and in sp schema.
In every table insert it's schema name.

Within sp make a SELECT from test_tbl, run it when all 3 tables exist.
You'll get the data from a table that is in sp's schema.

Now drop this table, run sp again.

This time you'll get the data from dbo.test_tbl.

Finally, drop dbo.test_tbl, run sp. This time you'll get an error.

Comment: Spot on.  I'll have to find a work around. Many thanks.